# Trouble finding bug in the merge sort algorithm implemented in Go

Tags: algorithm, sorting, go, merge

I want to implement a merge sort algorithm but was stuck in finding why my program fails to do the right sorting. I had tried to ask ChatGPT for some suggestions on it, but it couldn't help find where the bug is.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

// sortable is the interface that must be implemented by a type to be sorted by the merge sort.
type sortable interface {
    sort.Interface
    Set(i int, x any)
    At(i int) any
}

// IntSlice attaches the methods of sortable to []int, sorting in increasing order.
type IntSlice []int

func (x IntSlice) Len() int           { return len(x) }
func (x IntSlice) Less(i, j int) bool { return x[i] <= x[j] } // actually represents the `<=` operator
func (x IntSlice) Swap(i, j int)      { x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i] }
func (x IntSlice) Set(i int, a any)   { x[i] = a.(int) }
func (x IntSlice) At(i int) any       { return x[i] }

// merge two arrays into one
func merge(data sortable, lo, mid, hi int) {
    temp := make([]any, hi-lo+1)
    for i := lo; i <= hi; i++ {
        temp[i-lo] = data.At(i)
    }
    i, j := lo, mid+1
    for k := lo; k <= hi; k++ {
        if i > mid {
            data.Set(k, temp[j-lo])
            j++
        } else if j > hi {
            data.Set(k, temp[i-lo])
            i++
        } else if data.Less(i, j) { // actually represents the `<=` operator
            data.Set(k, temp[i-lo])
            i++
        } else {
            data.Set(k, temp[j-lo])
            j++
        }
    }
}
// recursive solving method
func mergeSort(data sortable, lo, hi int) {
    if hi-lo > 1 {
        mid := (lo + hi) / 2
        mergeSort(data, lo, mid)
        mergeSort(data, mid+1, hi)
        merge(data, lo, mid, hi)
    } else {
        if !data.Less(lo, hi) { // actually represents the `>` operator
            data.Swap(lo, hi)
        }
    }
}

func SortTtE(data sortable) {
    mergeSort(data, 0, data.Len()-1)
}

func main() {
    a := []int{10, 9, 11, 2, 7, 9, 6}
    SortTtE(IntSlice(a))
    fmt.Println(a)
// the false output: [2 6 9 7 10 11 9]
}
```

It might because I made mistakes in my control flow, so I was expecting someone to help me find where the bug is.
This is where the playground is: https://go.dev/play/p/AXZqZH2Ko1E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `merge`, you are modifying the array `data` at the same time you are checking for `data.Less`. This leads to an undefined state, because your actual data is stored in `temp` at that moment.

To fix this, perform the check on `temp`

```golang
func merge(data sortable, lo, mid, hi int) {
    temp := make([]int, hi-lo+1)
    for i := lo; i <= hi; i++ {
        // Notice I have to cast here, because temp it []int, 
        // but data is an interface
        temp[i-lo] = data.At(i).(int)
    }
    i, j := lo, mid+1
    for k := lo; k <= hi; k++ {
        if i > mid {
            data.Set(k, temp[j-lo])
            j++
        } else if j > hi {
            data.Set(k, temp[i-lo])
            i++
        } else if temp[i-lo] <= temp[j-lo] { // <- here, check against the actual data
            data.Set(k, temp[i-lo])
            i++
        } else {
            data.Set(k, temp[j-lo])
            j++
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is quite right. Now I am considering how to make the `temp`  of type `any` comparable, maybe implement the method at runtime such as the `Less` method implemented for IntSlice. But now I am not quite sure how to achieve this. All in all, very thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can make `temp` another `IntSlice`? Or at least something that has a `Less` method (maybe a `comparable` interface?) Checking type at run time is not necessarily a good idea generally speaking, it is very slow, and sometimes hints a bad design choices

Comment: make `temp` another `IntSlice` might not work, for my goal is to make this `merge` fuunction as universal as possible, not targetted for a specific type. Perhaps I must use some `reflect` to achieve this. Rewrap the `Less` method of `data` to a annoymous function `Less`  might be a good idea, I am considering how to do this.

Comment: I think I have got an answer. It might just be okay to bind a `clone` method to the IntSlice type to return the `sortable` interface. In this example, it will be `IntSlice(temp)`. @florent